# I cannot modify, delete file or change permissions as root

Tags: permissions

My server has been hacked - lots of Wordpress files were modified, one of the sites has been defaced. I cleaned everything and resored the site. Now Im left with one file that I cannot clean because I cannot edit out the malware code out of it. I can't delete the file or replace it nor change permissions (r--r--r--) as root owner. There are no error returned at all. I'm using command prompt, Ubuntu. I tried to delete the file under root and the user that it was created by, same result. Any hints or ideas how to solve this issue?

Command
sudo chmod -v 755 file.php
returns
mode of 'file.php' changed from 0444 (r--r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
But permissions dont change
when you do ls -l file.php
that returns -r--r--r--

Comment: Delete it while booting from Live Linux. Verify also your file-system.

Comment: You would not have this file if you really properly "cleaned everything and restored the site". Trying to revert an intrusion is a fool's errand; figure out how they got in, wipe the system, reinstall, close the hole, then restore from known-good backups.